# Update all the users specific property with http trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to make a function that after executing it needs to change one atribute in my entire user collection which will change from each user a specific property which is deviceToken

```
exports.changeDeviceToken = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    var db = admin.firestore();
    let snap = await db.collection('user').get()
    snap.forEach(async(doc) => {
       return await doc.data().update({
            deviceToken: ""
        })
    });
    res.status(200).send('Finished')
  });
```

This function is not updating my `deviceToken` property inside each user property , I need to replace what is in the deviceToken property with empty ""

it says that update is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const db = admin.firestore();

const getAllDocs = function(data) {
  const temp = []
  data.forEach(function (doc) {
    temp.push(doc.data())
  })
  return { data: temp }
}

exports.changeDeviceToken = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    let { data: snaps }  = await db.collection('user').get().then(getAllDocs)

    for (const snap of snaps) {
      // I'm not sure if you are reading your id this way...
      // make sure you adapt this part to your use case
      await db.collection('user').doc(snap.id).update({ deviceToken: "" })
    }
  
    res.status(200).send('Finished')
  });
```

The problem is the async code is not working in the way you are expecting, you can do it your way and use Promise.all to resolve em all, up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a batch write request ([see documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)). That way, all updates will happen in one request to firebase and you will save execution time.

Note that if you have more than 500 documents in your user collection, you will have to separate the request into several batches (with 500 updates each).

```
exports.changeDeviceToken = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    let db = admin.firestore();
    let batch = db.batch();

    let userSnapshot = await db.collection('user').get();
    
    userSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        batch.update(doc.ref, {
            deviceToken: ""
        });
    });

    await batch.commit();

    res.status(200).send('Finished')
});
```

Comment: Hi @Lunke can you update this code to do from 500 batches writes ?